# Is it possible to call a ClojureScript module from a jQuery or AngularJS normal webapp?

Tags: clojurescript

I have an existing web UI that I would like to be able to call a function written in ClojureScript. The function would be in a separate ClojureScript module (cs_func.js file) that does not need access to the DOM. I can't find any examples on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible (cf. [how to use a complex return object from clojurescript in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358954/)… for instance). As you already figured out, ClojureScript will be compiled to normal JavaScript files (where "normal" varies according to your cljsbuild settings on how aggressive the output will be optimized). This is more a Javascript question on how to access the compiled JavaScript module than anything else. 
You should be aware, however, that the output from cljsbuild might get mingled and that you probably want to prohibit this for your entrypoints, cf. the discussion in the section "Exporting ClojureScript functions" in this [article on ClojureScript/JavaScript interop](http://www.spacjer.com/blog/2014/09/12/clojurescript-javascript-interop/) and the even more detailed discussion in Luke VanderHarts article on [using JavaScript and ClojureScript](http://lukevanderhart.com/2011/09/30/using-javascript-and-clojurescript.html)